# I can get my video stream with gstreamer from command line with gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc but how can I take it with opencv videoCapture()

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, gst-launch-1.0, raspivid

I can get my video stream with gstreamer from command line with gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc but how can I take it with opencv videoCapture()
In my raspberry pi 3 I am streaming with raspivid and gst-launch-1.0 to my windows computer
In my windows I can take stream with gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc but I can't take from opencv VideoCapture()